# CSS Crop or Scale Image to DIV with 100% Width

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to crop (scale) an image in a DIV?

I've tried this, the right (black) portrait image will be cropped – the left (red) landscape image should be scaled and cropped as well. Is it possible with CSS only?

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4MuZ/

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: auto;
}
```

Comment: overflow: hidden on parent?

Comment: Please check http://jsfiddle.net/Q4MuZ/1/ ... do you think right way?

Answer (score 1):

To scale an image, you are on the right track. To crop an image you can put it inside an element (for example a div), then give it fixed dimensions and overflow: hidden.

Comment: If you achieve what you wanted... yes, but at the first glance it seems to do something different than what you asked (maybe I didn't get the question right). I thought you need overflow: hidden on each parent for image (to crop both of them) - right-crop and left-crop in your example.